# converting a string into a js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am probably doing a very small and fundamental mistake here. I am getting some information in the dom which exactly looks like this

```
<span id="pids" style="display:none">["26551826","22956811","22959266"]</span>
```

Which then I am trying to convert into a js array. For that I am doing this

```
var x = document.getElementById('pids');
var y = eval(x);

alert(y.length);
```

And the result is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/sbrmT/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :  http://jsfiddle.net/sbrmT/3/

```
var x = document.getElementById('pids').innerText; //you need to get the value
var y = JSON.parse(x); //dont use eval , json.parse will do.

alert(y.length);
```

Comment: *innerText* is an IE property copied by some, but not all, browsers. The standards–compliant equivalent is *textContent*. But since old IE doesn't support *textContent*, do something like `var el = document.getElementById('pids'); var x = el.textContent || el.innerText;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var x = document.getElementById('pids').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8vS2D/

```
var x = document.getElementById('pids');
var y = eval(x);

alert(eval(x.innerText));
```